# CSS Remove or rename a class on first-child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table TD which is created dynamically.
All the TDs created have a CLASS.
I have set the first-child Display to NONE.
I just need to remove or rename this class just on the first child.
Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this please?

Thanks

Comment: you should post some code example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('table td:first').removeClass('className')
```

or

```
$('table td:first').toggleClass('className')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".tdClass").get(0).className = "newClassName"
```

Should do what you want.
or

```
$($(".tdClass").get(0)).removeClass("tdClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation - http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

```
$(".myTable TD:first-child").removeClass("old-class-name").addClass("new-class-name");
```

or

```
$(".myTable TD:first-child").attr("class", "old-class-name");
```

Comment: The first-child selector matches more than one item. The :first selector matches only one, and is equivalent to .eq(0)

Comment: Very true. Given the lack of HTML code it was my assumption this is what the OP was looking to do. Ie. update the first child of multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

`$(#tableid td:first-child').removeClass('oldClass').addClass('newClass');` will work, provided that you substitute to correct id for `#tableid`.